# RTC Peer connections

Tags: html, reactjs, webrtc, rtcpeerconnection

I'm building social media application using node js and react js, I have problem when it comes to video / audio calls;
case 1: i call from computer to mobile phone and both are in same network, it works--
case 2: i call from mobile phone browser to computer and both are in same network, remote stream does not work--
case 3: i call from different network, remote stream does not work;--

i tried to change turn and stun servers but it did not work either;

The code;

```
function createPeer(userID: string, type: 'audio' | 'video') {
        const peer = new RTCPeerConnection(configuration); 
        peer.ontrack = onTrackEvent;
        peer.onicecandidate = onIceCandidateEvent(userID);
        return peer;
    }

    function onTrackEvent(e: RTCTrackEvent) {
        if (remoteStream.current) {
            e.streams[0].getTracks().forEach((track) => {
                remoteStream.current!.addTrack(track)
            });
        }
    }

function onIceCandidateEvent (userID: string) {
        return (e: RTCPeerConnectionIceEvent) => {
            if (e.candidate) {
                socket.emit('ice-candidate', {
                    userID,
                    candidate: e.candidate.candidate,
                    sdpMLineIndex: e.candidate.sdpMLineIndex,
                    sdpMid: e.candidate.sdpMid
                })
            }
        }
    }

function handlingAnswer({ sdp, myData, type }: { sdp: RTCSessionDescriptionInit, myData: any, type: 'audio' | 'video' } ) {
        if (peerConnection.current) {
            const desciption = new RTCSessionDescription(sdp);
            peerConnection.current.setRemoteDescription(desciption)
                .then(() => {
                    if (type === 'video') {
                        dispatch(callActions.gettingAnswerVideoCall(myData));
                    }

                    if (type === 'audio') {
                        dispatch(callActions.gettingAnswerVoiceCall(myData));
                    }
                })
        }
    }

const makeCall = async (userID: string, type: 'audio' | 'video') => {
        let constraints: MediaStreamConstraints = {};

        if (type === 'video') {
            constraints = {
                video: true, audio: true
            }
        } 

        if (type === 'audio') {
            constraints = {
                audio: true
            }
        }

        try {
            const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints);
            localStream.current = stream;
            remoteStream.current = new MediaStream();
            peerConnection.current = createPeer(userID, type);

            localStream.current.getTracks().forEach((track) => {
                peerConnection.current!.addTrack(track, localStream.current!)
            });

            const sdp = await peerConnection.current!.createOffer();
            await peerConnection.current!.setLocalDescription(sdp);
            
            const payload = {
                to: userID,
                caller: {
                    _id: userData!._id,
                    name: userData!.name,
                    username: userData!.username,
                    picture: userData!.picture
                },
                sdp,
                type
            }

            dispatch(callActions.callUser({
                callType: type,
                userID
            }))

            socket.emit('offer', payload)

        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    }

async function acceptCall(userID: string, sdp: RTCSessionDescriptionInit, type: 'video' | 'audio') {
        
        let constraints: MediaStreamConstraints = {};
        if (type === 'video') {
            constraints = { video: true, audio: true }
        }
        if (type === 'audio') {
            constraints = { audio: true }
        }

        try {
            const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints);
            localStream.current = stream;
            remoteStream.current = new MediaStream();
            peerConnection.current = createPeer(userID, type);
            localStream.current.getTracks().forEach((track) => {
                peerConnection.current!.addTrack(track, localStream.current!)
            })
            const sessionDescription = new RTCSessionDescription(sdp);
            await peerConnection.current.setRemoteDescription(sessionDescription);
            const answer = await peerConnection.current.createAnswer();
            await peerConnection.current.setLocalDescription(answer)

            if (type === 'audio') {
                dispatch(callActions.acceptVoiceCall())
            }

            if (type === 'video') {
                dispatch(callActions.acceptVideoCall())
            }

            const payload = {
                caller: userID,
                sdp: answer,
                myData: {
                    _id: userData!._id,
                    name: userData!.name,
                    username: userData!.username,
                    picture: userData!.picture
                },
                type
            }
            socket.emit('answer', payload)
        } catch (error) {
            alert(JSON.stringify(error))
        }    
    }

socket.on('offer', handlingOffer);

        socket.on('answer', handlingAnswer);

        socket.on('ice-candidate', async ({ candidate, sdpMLineIndex, sdpMid }) => {
            if (peerConnection.current) {
                const rtcIceCandidate = new RTCIceCandidate({ candidate, sdpMLineIndex, sdpMid });
                await peerConnection.current.addIceCandidate(rtcIceCandidate)
            }
        })

// In the Call Component
function CallComponent() {
   useEffect(() => {
       remoteVideoRef.current.srcObject = remoteStream.current
       myVideoRef.current.srcObject = localStream.current    
}, [])

return JSX .............................
}
```

Comment: How are you setting up your STUN TURN servers? Please add your configuration setup for that.

Comment: const configuration: RTCConfiguration = {
    iceServers: [
        { urls: 'stun:numb.viagenie.ca:3478' },
        {
            urls: 'turn:numb.viagenie.ca',
            credential: 'muazkh',
            username: 'webrtc@live.com'   
        },
    ],
    iceCandidatePoolSize: 10,
  };